# How long will the Google App Engine PHP 7.x runtime be supported?

Tags: php, google-app-engine

I would like to know about the PHP runtime support policy of Google App Engine.

Google App Engine seems to support PHP 7.2-7.4.

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php-gen2/runtime

However, 7.2 and 7.3 are no longer supported.
And 7.4 will end support on November 28, 2022.

https://www.php.net/supported-versions.php

How long will Google App Engine support these?

Answer (score 1):

The [Google App Engine documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/the-appengine-environments?hl=en#when-to-choose-the-standard-environment) explain that you can use only PHP 5.5, PHP 7.2, PHP 7.3, PHP 7.4, and PHP 8.1 (preview) versions.

So you can use PHP 7.4 and then migrate to PHP 8.1 or use PHP 8.1 in the preview from now on.

Comment: Thank you.

How long will Google App Engine support?

AzureAppService will end support at the same time as the PHP runtime. After that, it will be deleted irregularly.

I want to know when my application needs to be updated.

Comment: I don't know this answer @MP_okui ... sorry !